# Usage of LF on ReadLn in TIdTCPServer and WriteLn in TIdTCPClient

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, tcpserver

In my `TIdTCPServer.OnConnect` event, I receive information using:

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(LF, 5000)
```

I've read that `ReadLn()` expects `LF` on the end of strings, so do I need to add a `LF` at the end, like this?

```
TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('TEXT' + LF);
```

I see in `WriteLn()` it already include that automatically:

```
procedure TIdIOHandler.WriteLn(const AOut: string;
  AByteEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil
  {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}; ASrcEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil{$ENDIF}
  );
begin
                                                                                  
  // which encodes a LF character to byte $25 instead of $0A (and decodes
  // byte $0A to character #$8E instead of #$A).  To account for that, don't
  // encoding the CRLF using the specified encoding anymore, force the encoding
  // to what it should be...
  //
  // But, what to do if the target encoding is UTF-16?
  {
  Write(AOut, AByteEncoding{$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI, ASrcEncoding{$ENDIF);
  Write(EOL, Indy8BitEncoding{$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI, Indy8BitEncoding{$ENDIF);
  }

  // Do as one write so it only makes one call to network
  Write(AOut + EOL, AByteEncoding
    {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}, ASrcEncoding{$ENDIF}
    );
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, `IOHandler.WriteLn()` automatically sends `EOL` (aka `CRLF`) at the end of each string.  This is because most textual Internet protocols use `CRLF`.

`IOHandler.ReadLn()` expects `LF` by default if you omit the terminator, but whenever the terminator is `LF` (implicitly or explicitly) then `IOHandler.ReadLn()` will also handle `CRLF` as well.  So, DO NOT pass in your own `LF` to `IOHandler.WriteLn()`, eg:

```
TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('TEXT');
```

If you want to send `LF` instead of `CRLF`, use `IOHandler.Write()` instead, eg:

```
TCPClient.IOHandler.Write('TEXT' + LF);
```

Comment: What's the difference from LF to CRLF? as said i use AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(LF, 5000). so i don't need add "+ LF" at end of WriteLn on client side?

Comment: `LF` is 1 byte `0x0A`. `CRLF` is 2 bytes `0x0D 0x0A`. Most protocols standardized on `CRLF,` but many implementations are linient to accept just `LF`. As for using `+LF` with `WriteLn()`, I literally covered that in my answer. I would suggest using the `ReadTimeout` property instead of passing a timeout to `ReadLn()` directly, then you can omit the `LF` parameter, too. Then your code is just `WriteLn('TEXT')` and `ReadLn()`, which look more consistent with each other.

Comment: you mean AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout?

Comment: @PSDEVS Yes. You can certainly specify a timeout on each individual read if you really want to, but that is usually overkill. You can set the `ReadTimeout` up front instead, and then it will apply to all subsequent read operations. So then `...ReadLn(LF, 5000)` becomes `...ReadLn(LF)`, and `LF` is the default so that can be removed, too: `...ReadLn()`

Comment: Where add ReadTimeout instead at Context and on ReadLn?

Comment: @PSDEVS you can set it whenever you want, but ideally you would set it one time in the server's `OnConnect` event before you start your I/O reads/writes with the client in the `OnExecute` event.